# AWS Elasticsearch domain - Cloudformation template

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, aws-cloudformation

I am trying to create a Elasticsearch 2.3 domain in AWS using the following in CF template but for some reason I am unable to specify the version of Elasticsearch. Currently Amazon supports both 1.5 and 2.3. The error I get is

"Encountered unsupported property ElasticsearchVersion".

It just means the parameter to set the version is incorrect but i cant find what it needs to be anywhere in the documentation. Not specifying the property creates a Elasticsearch cluster in 1.5 version.

Template snippet:

```
`"ElasticsearchDomain": {
          "Type": "AWS::Elasticsearch::Domain",
          "Properties": {
            "DomainName": { "Ref" : "EsName" },
            "ElasticsearchVersion": "2.3",
            "ElasticsearchClusterConfig": {
              "DedicatedMasterEnabled": { "Ref" : "EsDedicatedMaster" },
              "InstanceCount": { "Ref" : "EsInstanceCount" },
              "ZoneAwarenessEnabled": "true",
              "InstanceType": { "Ref" : "EsInstanceType" },
              "DedicatedMasterType": { "Ref" : "EsMasterInstanceType" },
              "DedicatedMasterCount": "3"
            },
            "EBSOptions": {
              "EBSEnabled": true,
              "Iops": 0,
              "VolumeSize": { "Ref" : "EsEbsVolumeSize" },
              "VolumeType": { "Ref" : "EsEbsVolumeType" }
            },
            "SnapshotOptions": {
              "AutomatedSnapshotStartHour": "0"
            },
            "AccessPolicies": {
              "Version": "2012-10-17",
              "Statement": [{
                "Effect": "Allow",
                "Principal": {
                  "AWS": "*"
                },
                "Action": "es:*",
                "Resource": "*"
              }]
            },
            "AdvancedOptions": {
              "rest.action.multi.allow_explicit_index": "true"
            }
          }
        }`
```

Hoping someone has already solved this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok I had the same issue contacts AWS support they communicated me as Elastic Search 2.3 is very new Cloud Formation is not supporting the version property yet. So if you are using CFN you have to use the version 1.5.

Comment: Thanks this explains.

Comment: I don't know when the change was made but 2.3 is now a valid value for ElasticsearchVersion when provisioning ElasticSearch via CloudFormation.

Comment: Worked for me, even though I can't find `"ElasticsearchVersion"` in the docs. It's a direct child of `"Properties"` for `AWS::Elasticsearch::Domain`.